# Is it possible to use a Sqlite database over a LAN (multi-user)

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am working on a desktop application using VB.net which stores data on an sqlite database. The client says that they want the app to be accessed over the LAN by different departments. Is it possible that SQLIte can work in this setup?

Comment: `Is it possible that SQLIte can work in this setup?`, short answer is **yes**. Would I personally do this, ***no***... You are ***very limited*** on operations when you do this, for example: ***only one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in time***. Want more please see [**here**](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

Comment: yes SQLite database is just a file. You can place it on a shared network location and everyone, who has access to that location, can access it.

Example on how to use in dot net: http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Good luck.

Comment: What did you eventually do?

Answer (score -1):

No. SQLite isn't meant to be used by multiple clients at the same time (unless it is strictly read-only).

You should use a server style database (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.).

If you really want a file-based database, Access is the only one I know of that will work over a LAN with multiple users.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. SQLite can access database files on a network file system, and does handle concurrent accesses correctly (if the OS and the network implement locking correctly (many don't; see [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html))).

However, SQLite is a file-based database system; like Access, it is not really designed for network operation (see [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)).
Consider using a client/server database, if possible.

Comment: Access was designed for network operation. 20 years ago my job centered around building out Access based databases that lived on Network shares. We're talking Windows for Workgroups era tech.

Comment: As for SQLite, it doesn't even handle multiple threads writing to it from the same process, let along multiple computers. Even for simple applications I've got to throw a reader-writer lock around it to avoid collisions.

Comment: @JonathanAllen SQLite handles multiple threads and machines perfectly fine. If you get locking errors, you have configured a [timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) that is too short.

Comment: Playing with the timeout is just a work-around, not a real solution, and will only work under very light loads.